# Dismissing an Android popupwindow

Tags: java, android

I use a popupwindow in my activity that i would like to dimiss, but i see the following documentation about the dimiss() method for popup windows:

public void dismiss ()
Since: API Level 1

Dispose of the popup window. This method can be invoked only after showAsDropDown(android.view.View) has been executed. Failing that, calling this method will have no effect.
See Also

```
* showAsDropDown(android.view.View)
```

If I don't want to show the popup with showAsDropDown how else can u remove it from the main view?

Comment: Have you considered using the `finish();` function call that is implemented when ending an activity, or splash screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dismiss() will work as long as the PopupWindow is shown on screen.